# Setting my own probes with Dtrace in C++

Tags: c++, dtrace

I have some custom dtrace probes in a C-library, and when linking and using the library with a C application my probes work fine, however when linked against C++ it says it can't find them. The reason seems to be because of C++ mangling, and trying to get it to work has become a duck chase.

Any ideas?

Note: Using gcc

Answer (score 2):

So far I've found these "useful" links

[Using DTrace to Profile and Debug A C++ Program](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/dtrace_cc.html)

[Using DTrace SDT provider with C++](http://zvrba.net/tips/c++_dtrace.html)

but they haven't solved my problems.

Later on I found these articles:

[User-land tracing gets better and better](https://blogs.oracle.com/ahl/entry/user_land_tracing_gets_better) //this was very helpful

[Putting developer-defined DTrace probe points in an application](http://blogs.oracle.com/barts/entry/putting_user_defined_dtrace_probe)

[Dtrace Using SDT probes](http://www.filibeto.org/~aduritz/truetrue/solaris10/sdtprobes.pdf) //pdf that helped understand some details, but information is old

Basically it all boils down to using dtrace -h to headerfiles from ones probes.d

Comment: I found the link "User-land tracing gets better and better" invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `extern "C" { ... }` when declaring the C functions?